# iPhone SDK - TWTweetComposeViewController in a pre-ios 5 app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I realize that `TWTweetComposeViewController` is new to `iOS 5` (which is now a bit old in itself). I would like to still support pre `iOS 5` devices for my app however, so might I be able to control for this?

Would I need to do an OS version check and wrap the `TWTweetComposeViewController` in an if..else statement? Or is there another way to check and see if `TWTweetComposeViewController` is accessible?

Anyone have any idea?

Cheers,
Brett

Comment: You want this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8291345/how-can-i-improve-my-twtweetcomposeviewcontroller-code-in-ios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
if ([TWTweetComposeViewController class])
{
    // iOS 5 code
}
else
{
    // Older code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution here. I hadn't thought of this approach.
http://tonyngo.net/2011/10/twitter-integration-tutorial/